# Networking with closed ports at a school

Tags: java, networking, port

I teach an intro to programming class at a high school and I am trying to give a networking project for my students.  I was thinking that having them do a battleship type game would be very doable and I think they would really get jazzed up about it.  I can do this fine using sockets on my home computer, but at school all ports are closed and they aren't opening them up for me.

Is there a work around (like have a web service deal with relaying info around)? Any ideas?

(The class is basic and students don't have much background - I need to make it as simplified as possible).

Comment: Do you mean all ports are closed on individual computers? or are they closed on a firewall. If you are connecting to internal connections they might not have closed the ports.

Comment: How are all sockets blocked at school? Even intralan?

Comment: Do you have access to the web? If so, you could put up a simple server on appengine (or similar) that let's you post messages via a url, e.g. `http://myserver?from=foo&to=bar&msg=Mymessage` and send back the messages from others line by line, prefixed with the sender. To just poll, omit the to and msg params. Could be tested in a browser and the protocol is simple enough to be implemented via sockets or http clients

Comment: Off-topic, but, someone please help this teacher. If my teacher back at high school did anything close to this cool, that class would have done so much better. Instead, we practiced writing out code on paper and reciting it in front of the class. Thanks for making learning fun :-)

Comment: All ports are closed ? Please be more precise. Do you at least have access to a common and shared storage drive ? If so, you could use it and make a basic text-file based game. But again I'm not sure about your 'all ports are closed'.

Comment: All ports cannot possibly be closed, otherwise nothing would work. Please clarify.

Comment: You all are right.  The ports are closed from connecting from outside, but the lan does work.  I feel pretty silly.

Answer (score 1):

This servlet should work as advertised in the comment (haven't tested it):

Send a message with the URL parameters `to` and `message`

Receive a message with `get` (receiver id). Returns a message, or nothing if there is none. Should be testable with a browser.

In the real world, a get request should not really change the state of the server. I would only run this for the time of the class, as anybody can send stuff to any id, and anybody can read stuff for any id.

```
public class SimpleMessageServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private Map<String,String> messages = new HashMap<String,String>();

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
       throws ServletException, IOException {
    String to = request.getParameter("to");
    String message = request.getParameter("message");
    if (to != null && from != null && message != null) {
      messages.put(to, message);
    }
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    String get = request.getParameter("get");
    if (get != null) {
      String result = messages.remove(get);
      if (result != null) {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(result);
      }
    }
 }
```

Edit: Simplified to store only one message per address, should be enough for a turn based game and  buffering will just add complexity to the client logic (clearing out outdated turn data from previous matches etc.). Probably makes sense to sync up clients somehow, e.g. send a "start" signal before sending turns, and to discard anything until "start" is received. Sad thing is that this will require polling, using peer to peer sockets would be much nicer.